# is it fair to incompletely answer a question just to be first in?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, best-practices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

I read a question today, and there were two answers, one which didn't address the op's needs, and the second which only answered half the question. I formed a more complete answer, and after I posted it, the first answer was edited to be complete, with almost the exact answer that I posted. That answer ended up getting the upvote and the accepted answer, presumably because it appeared that we both answered with the same thing, and he answered first. In reality, he answered half first, then I answered completely, then he edited to complete it.

Is this a common practice, that I just need to accept, and get better at, or is it kind of a cheap move?

(additionally, my answer stated that his answer was missing half, and he commented saing "uhh mine has that," which just felt a bit insulting, as it clearly did not at first, and was edited)

Comment: Didn't see that before. Looks like a good discussion. this could be closed.